# Query for any matches in TableC where ssnNums[x] = SSN?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, arrays, winforms

Maybe someone can help me with building my query. I have a document-printed tracking table with 5 fields (TableC):

```
SSN
DATEC
TIMEC
PRINT_NEW
PRINT_OLD
```

When new Address Letters are printed a value is inserted into the table. Example data would be:

```
SSN        // 123456789
DATEC      // 20131202
TIMEC      // 133000
PRINT_NEW  // 2013-12-02-11.23.47.965000
PRINT_OLD  NULL
```

Then when the old address letters are printed, a value is inserted into `PRINT_OLD`:

```
PRINT_OLD  // 2013-12-05-09.15.37.276000
```

My below code is cycling through a listview control. `date` is the current date value and is the same for all items (this is needed for different function processing). As my `foreach` executes, each value of my `SSN` field is added to an array.

```
private void haveSelectedBeenPrinted()
    {
        string date = lvData.Items[0].SubItems[13].Text.ToString();
        // Get # Items in lvData, use to set Array Size
        int ssnCnt = lvData.Items.Count;
        string[] ssnNums = new string[ssnCnt];
        int x = 0;
        foreach (ListViewItem lvI in lvData.Items)
        {
            ssnNums[x] = lvI.SubItems[16].Text;
            x++;
        }


    }
```

Now what I need to do is create a query that will check TableC for any instances of one of the SSN's in my array and the date value (`DATEC`) being the current days date. This is to tell whether a selected item in the listview (SSN identified) has had a document for that SSN printed already for today. Ideally, I need to return those where the SSN has a had the new address document letter printed today (WHERE SSN = ssnNums[x] AND DATEC = currentDate()) and alert users which ones have already been printed, then prompt them whether to continue processing or let them deselect the already printed record.

Theoretically, users can change their address on record multiple times. But we only want to generate and mail a notice letter once per day.

Can anyone assist with this?

EDIT:

Would the following seem appropriate for what I'm after?

```
private void haveSelectedBeenPrinted()
    {
        string date = lvData.Items[0].SubItems[13].Text.ToString();
        // Get # Items in lvData, use to set Array Size
        int ssnCnt = lvData.Items.Count;
        string[] ssnNums = new string[ssnCnt];
        int x = 0;
        foreach (ListViewItem lvI in lvData.Items)
        {
            ssnNums[x] = lvI.SubItems[16].Text;
            x++;
        }

        string query = "";
        query = "SELECT SSN FROM BOTHLIB.BAC000PF WHERE ";
        for (int i = 0; i < ssnNums.Length; i++)
        {
            query += "SSN = " + ssnNums[i] + " AND DATEC = " + date;
            if (i != ssnNums.Length)
            {
                query += " OR ";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in a table value parameter full of the ssn values you want to query in to a stored procedure and then do a join on the TVP and tableC.

Table Value Parameter:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[SsnList] AS TABLE(
     [Ssn] CHAR(9) NOT NULL
)
```

Stored Procedure:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPrintedDocuments]
    @ssnList SsnList READONLY,
    @printedDate DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT SSN
           , DATEC
           , TIMEC
           , PRINT_NEW
    FROM TableC
         INNER JOIN @ssnList ON TableC.SSN = SsnList.Ssn
         WHERE TableC.DATEC = @printedDate
END
GO
```

Method for calling the stored proc:

```
private List<Foo> GetPrintedSsns(SqlConnection connection, DataTable table)
{
    var foos = new List<Foo>();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandTimeout = configuration.CommandTimeout;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "GetPrintedDocuments";
        var parameter = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SsnList", table);
        parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var foo = new Foo();
                //Map properties to object
                foos.Add(foo);
            }
        }
    }
    return foos;
}
```

The DataTable parameter in the code should be a System.Data.DataTable with a schema that matches the table value parameter.

EDIT: This is MS SQL Server code.  It won't solve your problem as it is written.

EDIT 2: You might be able to do it with a common table expression.

```
WITH 
      SsnList (SSN) AS
        (SELECT *
           FROM VALUES(--Append comma delimited ssn list here))
   SELECT THIS_EMP.EMPNO, THIS_EMP.SALARY, DINFO.AVGSALARY, DINFO.EMPCOUNT, 
                              DINFOMAX.AVGMAX
     FROM SsnList
     INNER JOIN TableC ON SsnList.SSN = TableC.SSN
     WHERE TableC.DATEC = --Today
```

I wish had an environment to help test that before I slapped it up there, but that should be a good start for a non MSSQL environment.

Comment: Can that work if my table resides inside a libary on an ibm midrange system (AS400)?